# Replace and conversion is converting to NULL in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a scenrio in which I have to remove some text from date and then convert them into DATETIME. but when I using below method it is resulting in NULL output.

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('2017-09-21','',NULL) AS DATETIME)
```

Same output is coming when using CONVERT. Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Replace an empty string with NULL? IE replace nothing with an Unknown?

Comment: What text are you attempting to remove? If you are trying to remove spaces then you would switch that to REPLACE('2017-09-21',' ',''). That would get rid of excess spaces for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql):

> Returns NULL if **any** one of the arguments is NULL.

You pass `NULL` as last argument.

You could use [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) instead of `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT CAST(NULLIF('20170921', '') AS DATETIME)
```

This will return `NULL` if the string is empty and a casted `datetime` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You *did* specify NULL. In SQL (all products) NULL means *UNKNOWN*. Applying any function to an unknown value results in an unknown result, hence NULL. The exception are the functions specifically meant to deal with NULLs.

It's hard to understand how your expression can be fixed though, since you try to replace an empty string with NULL. What is the empty string supposed to match?

Comment: I guess he wants to replace the empty string with `NULL` and the non-empty with a valid `datetime`. My suggestion is to use `NULLIF` then.